# Don't know what is updating ALL my stats - causing IO problems

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, performance

Woke up this morning with a page that our cluster was down. It came back up right away. I found log error logs with entries about IO taking longer than 15 seconds. Our monitoring server had tried to ping the server and had a timeout error.

I checked one of our monitoring tools to see what was going on at 4:30 in the morning. It seems to be statistics being updated on one of our large databases. The tool shows our disk being maxed out. I see very high % busy times for one of the disks.

Now sqlagent is progressing through subsequent databases alphabetically doing the same thing! We do have auto update stats on - but I thought that happened on a as-needed basis. I don't have any statistics update jobs enabled right now(that I know of - and the job monitor doesn't show any running jobs), so I'm not really sure whats causing this.  Also, it's the middle of the night, so there wouldn't be users on these systems updating rows.

http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;195565 - confirms my thoughts on the as-needed nature of autostats.

The same thing also happened last night around 6:30pm - on the same large database - a few select statsman from... statements.

sqlagent is running the commands.

The disks are on a SAN and we're running the latest version of sql 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an [event notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453.aspx). The MSDN list of [DDL events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510452.aspx) doesn't list the statistics event(s), but they are valid sources of DDL notifications and will fire. Your notification message will contain the SPID, the LOGIN and and the actual T-SQL statement that triggered the statistics operation.

Comment: Interesting idea, but I know when they are happening and that the sqlagent account is running them.  I just don't know what is telling the agent to run them.  Perhaps as a result of an action in SSIS?  Not an explicit statistics step, but some sort of data operation?

Comment: This will be good for getting on the issue when it happens.

Comment: The activity was actually being picked up by DDL audit triggers on our system.  It helped us track it down to being accidentally run from a development machine.

Comment: Marked as answer as it was the closest to being correct :)

Answer (score 1):

Turn off auto-update stats tonight and see if the problem is replicated. If not, then you may have to manage the stats updates yourself.

Comment: This seems like it may be the route to go.  I'm conferring with the SAN gods right now.  We're hitting 300/MB/s at peaks. 

I turned the auto update OFF for a certain massive database and I still see these calls happening last night...